# How can i write code for divisibility in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

How can i write VHDL code for 4-digit binary numbers so that it outputs 1 only when the 4-digit number is divisible by 3 or 4 using only NOR gates?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you not use a lookup table?

Comment: As James mentioned, a LUT is probably the best answer. If you have to use only NOR gates, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. Because you can build *any* logic with only NAND and NOR.

Answer (score 1):

1) List the numbers (3,4 etc) for which the output is to be 1.
2) Write down the binary representation of each of these numbers, 0011, 0100, etc
3) Write down the expression for the output as the logical OR of these terms :
Output <= 0011 + 0100 + ... 
This is the expression for your output in SOP (Sum of Products) form.
4) Optionally, (but worth doing because it reduces the size of the problem you are dealing with) minimise this expression using standard techniques such as drawing the Karnaugh map, and combining adjacent terms to simplify the expression.
5) Use De Morgan's rules to transform the simplified SOP expression into POS (Product of Sum) form.
6) You can now implement the POS form as two levels of NOR gate.

Answer (score 1):

One best way I guess was to manually derive the equations from truth table through karnaugh map you will get a combination of AND and OR gate convert all that to NOR gate using standard technique after that you can go for implementing the same using gate level modelling.